# How to get max date, given in unix timestamp from hive query/pyspark

Tags: python, max, min, apache-spark-sql

I have a date column in unix timestamp as follows:

`%sql select timestamp from table where date_column = 'date=2018053000' limit 5`

```
1527688604
1527688608
1527688610
1527688612
1527688616
```

Now, with this query, I am able to convert to date 
`%sql select from_unixtime(timestamp) as timestamp2 from table where date_column = 'date=2018053000' limit 5`

```
timestamp2

    2018-05-30 13:56:44
    2018-05-30 13:56:48
    2018-05-30 13:56:50
    2018-05-30 13:56:52
    2018-05-30 13:56:56
```

I want to get the max date value. I tried some stack overflow answers but none of them give me expected results.

I am trying to find both max and min dates out of my results. This is just 5 results using `limit 5` but in actual I want to do on the entire result set.

Comment: Does it works limit 1,1 for min and limit 5,1 for max?

Comment: @Davide: There are more items. I just used limit 5 to show a sample of data.

Comment: Why can't you just do `select max(timestamp), min(timestamp) from table where ...`?

Comment: @pault: the timestamp is in utc. If I do that, it gives wrong answer.

Comment: @Atihska please explain how it's the wrong answer. Can you provide an example? Correct me if I'm wrong but timestamps should be monotonic, even if they're utc. Any conversion still maintains order, no? OR are you asking for the max timestamp for a given day (in different timezone)?